# How to remove this error in media player app?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am making an Media player app in android i am stuck bcoz of this error can anyone helpme for this.
The code is this -

```
private void loadAudio() {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
            String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                audioList = new ArrayList<>();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                     title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                     album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                     artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

                    // Save to audioList
                    audioList.add(new MediaStore.Audio(data,title,album,artist));
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

The error is in this line -
 audioList.add(new MediaStore.Audio(data,title,album,artist));
error says that i cannot add string to this method

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Edit your question with the code....

Comment: A *photo* of a *screen* posted to see the error? Really?

Comment: then what should i post?

Comment: error **text** and code as **text**

Comment: is it fine now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new Audio object that you have created and not the **MediaStore.Audio()**.like below

//what need to be done, here Audio is your pojo class

```
audioList.add(new Audio(data,title,album,artist));
```

//what you are doing

```
audioList.add(new MediaStore.Audio(data, title,album,artist));
```

Comment: Hi i am new for this , the line which u told i wrote that first but when i did Alt+Enter at Audio it changes to the code i pasted.

Comment: What is the name of the pojo class you have created?